# Something like rsync with the iPhone-sdk

Tags: iphone

I'm looking for an efficient means of copying an online file to the local iPhone. Something like RSync would be an ideal technology to use, since it only transfers the bytes that are different; does anyone have experience with anything that fits my description?

What I'm specifically trying to accomplish is the transfer of an SQLite database hosted via http to the iPhone. I expect the database to grow in time; hence my search for an efficient means of transferring the data to the iPhone.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the source for an iPhone platform. Maybe you could make an RSync port and release it for the community?

Comment: That sounds like a worthwhile idea, but I can't tackle it for this version though - I'm running on a hard deadline.

Answer (score 0):

I would have the app query the database for the changes and then download and store the changes in the local database.  Treating the database as an opaque file results in a partially downloaded database that is useless and partial downloads could happen quite frequently with mobile devices.